# Computing differences accross rows with multiple index columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column representing time, and additional columns representing other parts of the key.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(t, l1, l2, t * t * (1 + l2 + l1)) 
                        for t in range(3) 
                        for l1 in [3, 4] 
                        for l2 in [10, 100]], 
                  columns=['t', 'l1', 'l2', 'x'])

    t   l1  l2  x
0   0   3   10  0
1   0   3   100 0
2   0   4   10  0
3   0   4   100 0
4   1   3   10  14
5   1   3   100 104
6   1   4   10  15
7   1   4   100 105
8   2   3   10  56
9   2   3   100 416
10  2   4   10  60
11  2   4   100 420
```

I'm looking for the difference in the 'x' column for the row with the previous value of 't', but the same values for 'l1', and 'l2'.

```
    t   l1  l2  x   t.1 delta_x
0   0   3   10  0   1   NaN
1   0   3   100 0   1   NaN
2   0   4   10  0   1   NaN
3   0   4   100 0   1   NaN
4   1   3   10  14  2   14.0
5   1   3   100 104 2   104.0
6   1   4   10  15  2   15.0
7   1   4   100 105 2   105.0
8   2   3   10  56  3   42.0
9   2   3   100 416 3   312.0
10  2   4   10  60  3   45.0
11  2   4   100 420 3   315.0
```

I can generate this frame with the following code.

```
df['t.1'] = df.t + 1
df['delta_x'] = df.x - df.merge(df, left_on=['t', 'l1', 'l2'], 
                                right_on=['t.1', 'l1', 'l2'], 
                                how='left', 
                                suffixes=['','.1'])['x.1']
```

Is there a cleaner or more efficient way to do this?

Comment: A possibly simpler and easier for future devs to follow and modify way would be to split the dataframe apart on values of (l1,l2), do the series calculations, and remerge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `l1` and `l2` columns as you want to compare the difference of `x` column for the pair of these values(`l1, l2`) depending on the change in value of `t` column.

By default, [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) computes the difference between the value of (`t=1`) and (`t=0`) grouped by `l1 & l2` and returns the result. So, if you want to find the difference in `x` values between (`t=2`) and (`t=0`), you just need to do `diff(periods=2)`.

And, finally use the [`tranform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) method to return the computed diffs within each group of the group chunk.

```
In [3]: df['delta_x'] = df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
    t  l1   l2    x  delta_x
0   0   3   10    0      NaN
1   0   3  100    0      NaN
2   0   4   10    0      NaN
3   0   4  100    0      NaN
4   1   3   10   14     14.0
5   1   3  100  104    104.0
6   1   4   10   15     15.0
7   1   4  100  105    105.0
8   2   3   10   28     14.0
9   2   3  100  208    104.0
10  2   4   10   30     15.0
11  2   4  100  210    105.0
```

**Timing Constraints:**

```
In [5]: %timeit df['delta_x'] = df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.55 ms per loop

In [17]: %timeit df['delta_x'] = df.x - df.merge(df, left_on=['t', 'l1', 'l2'], right_on=['t.1', 'l1', 'l2'],how='left',suffixes=['','.1'])['x.1']
100 loops, best of 3: 3.33 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
def diff(x):
    return x - x.shift()

df['delta_x'] = df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].apply(diff)
```

#### Implement MAXU's comment below in my answer.

```
df['delta_x'] = df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].diff()
```

Comment: IMO you don't need your own `diff()` function and a slow `apply()` method, you can simply use standard [GroupBy.diff()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) - `df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].diff()`

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was

```
df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].diff()
```

Interestingly Nickil's method seems to be faster.

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(t, l1, l2, t * t * (1 + l2 + l1))
                        for t in range(3)
                        for l1 in [3, 4]
                        for l2 in [10, 100]],
                  columns=['t', 'l1', 'l2', 'x'])

N = 1000

t = timeit.timeit("df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].transform(lambda x: x.diff())", setup='from __main__ import df', number=N)
print(t)  # 1.8100

def diff(x):
    return x - x.shift()

t = timeit.timeit("df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].apply(diff)", setup='from __main__ import df, diff', number=N)
print(t)  # 2.6829

t = timeit.timeit("df.groupby(['l1', 'l2'])['x'].diff()", setup='from __main__ import df', number=N)
print(t)  # 2.5710
```